Space between text and footnotes
Is there a way in InDesign to change the distance between footnotes and text differently for different pages?
I need to put a full page graphic on the 'next' page and need to minimize the gap between the text and the notes on the previous page to accomplish this (but want to keep the distance for all other pages).
Thanks!

I don't really use footnotes, but can't you merely select the note you need to alter and adjust the space before options? That shouldn't change any other page.

I don't believe that will work. The footnote is within it's own area. I don't believe it qualifies as its own frame, since it is part of the larger text frame of the entire page.

There's no obvious way to do it but why don't you cheat the leading and paragraph spacing minutely on the page to create the space. It shouldn't be noticeable. If it is, I'd try another approach, i.e., adjusting tracking in paragraphs with one or two words on the last line (runts). To make sure it's not noticeable, I'd stick to around -5.
